# How to use Mockito/PowerMockito to trigger IOException for Unit/Integration Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, integration-testing, powermockito

I am doing testing on the following piece of code, and i am having trouble getting this method to throw an IOException so i can get 100% coverage.
I have tried to mock the CharArrayReader, StringWriter classes but to no avail.
Would appreciate any help!

Class to test

```
public static final String getValue(String content) {
    if (content == null) return null;
    CharArrayReader reader = new CharArrayReader(content.toCharArray());
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        int c;
        while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
            if (isChinese((char)c)) {
                writer.write(c);
            } else {
                if ( (char)c > 0x20 && (char)c < 0x7f ) {
                    writer.write(c);
                } else {
                    writer.write(' ');
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    return writer.toString();
}
```

My Attempts

```
@Test
public void getValue_Exception() throws IOException {
    String content = "asd";
    char[] chara = null;
    CharArrayReader reader = mock(CharArrayReader.class);
    when(content.toCharArray()).thenReturn(chara);
    
    when(reader.read()).thenThrow(IOException.class);
    StringWriter writer = mock(StringWriter.class);
    doThrow(IOException.class).when(writer).write(anyInt());


    spyController.getValue(content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only scenario, in which `CharArrayReader::read` throws `IOException` is when the stream is closed. In your example it seems rather impossible.

Nevertheless, if you really want to get that 100% coverage or just make sure your class behaves in case of unexpected, my advise would be to create a factory for your reader e.g.:

```
class ReaderFactory {
    Reader create(String content) {
        return new CharArrayReader(content.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

With this class in place, you could use it in your code and mock the `create` method. This way you would have control over the instance of `Reader` being used in your test case.

Answer (score 0):

While reading inside the `CharArrayReader` class, the `IOException` is thrown when the `char[] buff` parameter in the constructor is `null`.

```
private void ensureOpen() throws IOException {
    if (buf == null)
        throw new IOException("Stream closed");
}
```

One approach (even if it is a bad idea to mock the String class) is to mock the call of the method `toCharArray()` from the `String` class to return a `null` value.